# Configuring SSH server to require RSA key

Tags: ssh, rsa, ssh-keys, openssh

I'm trying to configure my SSH server to require users to have an RSA key. To do this I have the settings in `sshd_config` set to

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and

```
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and

```
UsePAM no
```

Then I do `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart` to restart the server.

This seems to work to some degree, because I included my macs `rsa_key` and it lets me log in without asking for a password. However when I try to `ssh` in through a computer that I haven't included the key of, it just prompts me for my password, and then when entered, lets me in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you're not reloading your ssh config correctly. Which Linux distribution/version are you using (assuming you're even using Linux)?

In Ubuntu I usually do:

```
sudo restart ssh
OR
sudo service ssh restart
```

Additionally, though not germane to this question - ideally root should not have a password - you should use be using sudo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no 
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

otherwise even if `sshd` does not ask itself for a password, it will trust `PAM` and `login` which will authenticate the user with its password.

While testing, make sure to have another way in in case a problem occurs with SSH...
And make sure you restart your server with `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`.

Comment: I had `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` already set to no and I switched `UsePAM` to no, but still no luck

Comment: Are you using the root account or a regular account?

Comment: I think root is immune to those settings. Try `PermitRootLogin without-password` ? Can you also try with a regular user?

Comment: Do you mean, set `PermitRootLogin` to no? I don't have a regular user set up at the moment, but I don't see how that could possibly be. If you wanted to force people to have an RSA key wouldn't that be especially true of a user with root access?

Comment: No I mean, as written, `PermitRootLogin without-password`

Comment: Tried it but no change. Perhaps I'm not restarting the ssh server correctly?

Comment: Make sure you restart with `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` and not `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` as you write in your question

Comment: `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` dosen't work for me, I get `sudo: /etc/init.d/sshd: command not found` and when I look in `/etc/init.d/` there is no script `sshd` only `ssh`.

Comment: Ok then no further idea.